# how to register extended scalar

Tags: spring-graphql

graphql beta testers,

experimenting with 1.0.0-M6 and wondering how I can register custom scalars from the widely used [graphql-java-extended-scalars](https://github.com/graphql-java/graphql-java-extended-scalars) project.
I added

```
@Bean
public GraphQLScalarType json() {
    return ExtendedScalars.Json;
}
```

in my application class and

```
scalar JSON
```

in my schema file but the the scalar is not picked up during application startup.

Can anyone help ?

Regards,
Dirk

Answer (score 8):

You can register a custom scalar by contributing a `RuntimeWiringConfigurer` bean to your application, like this:

```java
@Configuration
public class GraphQlConfig {

    @Bean
    public RuntimeWiringConfigurer runtimeWiringConfigurer() {
        return wiringBuilder -> wiringBuilder.scalar(ExtendedScalars.Json);
    }
}
```

Comment: Source: https://github.com/graphql-java/graphql-java-extended-scalars

Comment: how to register multiple data type?

Comment: @AntiMafia You can chain multiple `scalar()` methods together as they return the `wiringBuilder` instance back.